# What's a good illustration of the alternate PCT bear-bag hanging method?

Tags: camping, bear-bags

Illustration of the *standard* "PCT bear bag hanging method"[1] is easily found by search engines, e.g.

https://theultimatehang.com/2013/03/19/hanging-a-bear-bag-the-pct-method/

The *alternate* PCT method is demonstrated in this video:
https://youtu.be/Y3lEiisY5cU?si=m_9FVVrVhzrgFkJ1&t=625

But it seems very hard to find a good written instruction with illustration for the *alternate* PCT bear bag hanging method. Any suggestion?

[1] PCT: Pacific Crest Trail

Comment: If you could include a screenshot of the first method and a link or a quote of some text for the alternate method, that would be helpful.

Comment: I found an instructional video on the topic, which *does* include the alternate method (for when you can't find a branch sufficient to get 6' away from the trunk and 20'+ of height to work with) [here](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=Y3lEiisY5cU). As mentioned in the OP, no illustration of the latter

Comment: This Q seems to assume we know what the *standard* and *alternate* PCT bear hangs are ... as well as know how they differe from non-PCT bear hangs!

Comment: @MartinF yes, though I was able to find the two methods in video form - see the link in my prior comment. Not sure whether that’s better as a place to start an answer from or as additional context to add to the question.

Comment: Another video is [here](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=QkuxwpMcpfM). It shows 4 methods, including standard and alternate PCT methods. And [this](https://www.cleverhiker.com/essential-trail-skills/episode-8-protect-your-food-keep-wildlife-wild) is an article, with video, showing both PCT methods..

Comment: Too much jargon in the question and the linked instructions.  I'd guess the PCT is Pacific Coast Trail, and the acronym is just naming a region where it is strongly encouraged.  The PCT methods toss a rope over a branch and use a toggle to make a large loop hanging from the branch.  The standard method using a toggle in the free end below the carabiner to make a loop no larger than the bag-to-toggle distance, and the alternate method uses the toggle on the  inside of the loop to make a loop no smaller than the bag-to-toggle distance, anchoring the loose end to a tree.